# In the 9th line i am getting a error "Shape of passed values is (1, 5), indices imply (5, 1)"

Tags: python, linear-regression

Here is my a part of my python code for implementing linear-regression. The problem is occurring in the lastline

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, 
test_size=0.4, random_state=101)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(lm.intercept_)
lm.coef_
X_train.columns
cdf = pd.DataFrame(lm.coef_, X.columns, columns = ['Coeff'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your trying to fit an array with shape (5, 1) into a column vector of shape (1, 5).

the LinearRegression.coef_ attributes return an array of shape (n_features,) or (n_targets, n_features) (from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

In your case X.columns should return something of shape (1, n). This is a mismatch in shape and pandas returns an error.

Try reshaping one of these two, or transposing and you should not have the error anymore.

Comment: please tell me how can i reshape

Comment: you can use numpy (numpy.reshape([your array], [new_shape])